# editing a multidimensional array with [index]es, not only [name]s

Tags: php, function, multidimensional-array, foreach

```
public $form = array (  
    array(  
        'field' => 'email',  
        'params' => array(  
            array(  
                'rule' => 'email',  
                'on' => 'create',  
                'required' => true,  
                'error' => 'The email is invalid!'  
            ),  
            array(  
                'rule' => 'email',  
                'on' => 'update',  
                'required' => false,  
                'error' => 'The email is invalid!'  
            )  
        )  
    )  
);


public function onlyNeeded($action) {
    $form = $this->form;
    $action = $this->action;

    foreach ($form as $formelement) {
        $field = $formelement['field'];
        $paramsgroup = $formelement['params'];
        if ($paramsgroup['on'] != $action) {
            form = removeparamsgroup($form, $action);
            }
        }
    return $form;
}
```

How do I do the `removeparamsgroup()` function?

There are [index]es, not only [name]s!

Do you know what I mean?

array(array( twice!

Comment: Could you explain more? I dont understand.

Comment: I need to delete the $paramsgroup from the $form when $action = $paramsgroup['on'], but unset is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the array key in the foreach loop, you can unset the correct array index using using that. You also need to loop over each param of each form element, which you  weren't doing in your example.

```
public function onlyNeeded($action) {
    $form = $this->form;

    //get $formelement by reference so it can be modified
    foreach ($form as & $formelement) {

        //$key becomes the index of current $param in $formelement['params']
        foreach ($formelement['params'] as $key => $param) {
           if ($param['on'] != $action) {
               unset($formelement['params'][$key]);
           }
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: nice job, you beat me too it ;)

Answer (score 0):

unset($form['params']) ? What do you mean by remove?

Comment: Ya i'm lost too.  I don't understand the question.

Comment: when the 'action' = create, param arrays with 'on' = 'update' should be deleted from the form array

array(  
'rule' => 'email',  
'on' => 'update',  
'required' => false,  
'error' => 'The email is invalid!'  
)

Comment: I've just tried $form = unset($paramsgroup), but then my IDE highlited unset as an error!

Comment: Maybe, I should call it param*sub*group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function onlyNeeded($action) {
    $form = $this->form;

    foreach ($form as &$formelement) {
        foreach ($formelement['params'] as $key => $paramsgroup)
        {
            if ($paramsgroup['on'] != $action)
                unset($formelement['params'][$key]);
        }
    }
    return $form;
}
```

Don't forget the & sign in the first foreach loop or it won't work.  Without the & sign foreach copies each element instead of returning a reference.